# Solution to manage web to lead maximum daily limit

Tags: leads, web2lead

We plan to use the web to lead form on one of our landing pages on our sites. The issue is the maximum limit of 500 leads per day which prevents our sales reps to immediately view the leads and act on them. The issue is that we have to wait 24 hours to see the leads who exceeded the limit and we get only emails to the admin at the moment. 
 The only solution is to use the lead api and insert the lead directly. Have any of you guys created a custom lead form which replicates the web to lead form using the api which can be embedded on multiple websites? Any apps or code for this please?
Thanks
Buyan

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depending on how many leads you are getting daily, you may be able to plead your case to your rep and get the value increased. Shell Black has [verified this is possible](http://www.shellblack.com/marketing/web-to-lead/).

If it is consistently much higher, you would be better off creating a custom solution to generate your leads via the API.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Have you gone through this yourself?

Comment: No, I haven't personally. However, I would assume it should be possible for Salesforce to up that limit (especially considering it has been verified it is possible). How many leads are you getting per day via web-to-lead? I would assume as long as it isn't drastically higher, you might be alright.

Answer (score 4):

As for apps that you can use to collect the leads, I'm a fan of Form Assembly. Easy to setup, maintain and does some snazzy lookup logic so you can avoid dupes.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, the first and easiest thing to do is file a case / contact your AE and request this limit be lifted. They will hopefully do this for you; raising it to 1000 isn't normally a big deal for Salesforce.

If they don't do this, then you'll need to get the Leads into SF via the API (presuming you have Professional with the API add on, or Enterprise or higher).

I've seen people do this every which way, but your options can be grouped into three areas:

1) Write some custom code. This can be php/cgi/asp/whatever that grabs the lead data and either uploads it right away or puts it in a temporary CSV and runs a batch update every hour or so. You can also add spam checking, validation, captchas, whatever you might need to enhance this.

2) Use a form tool. This can be hosted, like FormAssembly or other tools you can find on the AppExchange (we find FormAssembly very powerful) or it can be something like Wordpress-based Gravity Forms with the Salesforce API add on. Form Assembly has some other nifty options, like letting a form create two or more records across multiple objects from a single form, and it also lets you email out a URL which links to a pre-filled form (handy for letting people update their own data without the cost / hassle of a customer portal).

3) Consider something more powerful and more expensive, like Hubspot, which will improve your marketing and also passes leads to Salesforce through the API. This is overkill in many scenarios, but if you are getting 500 leads in a day, you might want automation and a few other things that Hubspot gives you. Other options in this category are Marketo, Eloqua, and Pardot.

Regardless of what you choose, might I also suggest taking a look at [Daddy Analytics](http://daddyanalytics.com). We provide information on where your leads come from. You'll know what website they were on beforehand, what adword they clicked, what tweet they followed in, and what page they landed on. This information is included when your lead converts to an opportunity, so you can start running reports and see where your Revenue is coming from in terms of Lead Source / Marketing Activity.

best of luck!
Stony, CEO of Daddy Analytics

Answer (score 1):

I'd second that. If you are getting 500 plus leads a day you should really invest in a Marketing Automation platform.

Hubspot is fairly simple to set up and use (compared to Marketo and Eloqua), but it would really depend on your budget and what you are trying to accomplish.

Long story short though - at 500 leads per day, you'd likely convert a lot more of them into sales if you were using a product like Hubspot, Eloqua, Marketo or Pardot. If you give some more detail on what your budget and technical chops are I could likely provide a recco. They all accomplish the same things, just at varying levels of cost/difficulty to implementation/employee training required.